# Should I answer my own question when the solution is too simple?

Tags: discussion

I recently asked a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/791892/black-screen-after-login-on-account) about my screen going black after the login. It turns out that I made a really stupid mistake. My laptop with Ubuntu has a shortcut on the keyboard that allows me to toggle between monitors. When there is no other monitor connected the build-in screen simply goes black.
I could post the solutions as an answer to my own question but the bottom line is *don't be stupid*. Also, it's also only applicable for this specific type of laptop I reckon.

What do you, as a community, recommend? Answer my own question or explain the solution to the people trying to help me and delete the question in a few days?

Comment: If you really think it is too localized, you can flag it as such. :)

Answer (score 23):

Yes, answer the question, you are encouraged to answer your own question, how simple it is, is irrelevant, you can even accept your own answer (though you don't get the +15 or +2 rep).

Many people overlook things and we have all asked questions like this, it seems reasonable, to me, that if you overlooked this, then others may too but don't write anything like " don't be stupid.", keep it professional.

Don't edit it in to your question like you have currently, use the answer space for the answer and you should mention the laptop make and model, if you think it is specific to that hardware.

There is no need for you to come back and delete it, it will be fine.

Comment: Thanks. It's not my intention to write an answer like ¨don't be stupid". I was trying to explain that the solution is a very simple one. Also, I was still be a little frustrated with myself after spending a great deal of time trying to figure out the problem when I wrote that :)

Comment: @Iarwain answer it but make it look more complicated ;-)